# AutoHotKey => assign key combination to key combination

Tags: autohotkey

I use Alt+J/K/L/I instead of Left/Down/Right/Up keys. It's straightforward:

```
!k::Send {Down Down}
```

Now I decided to add Shift to this sequence and use it to expand selection Left/Down...  I tried difference ways, read multiple posts - nothing helps.
For example this:

```
!k:: 
if GetKeyState("Shift")
{
        Send {+Down Down}
        return
}
else
{
    Send {Down Down}
}
return
```

Or this:

```
!k::
    If GetKeyState("Shift")
        Send {+Down Down}
    Else
        Send {Down Down}
Return
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell your HotKey to "Accept" other modifiers by adding an *.
Otherwise <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> will be ignored (unless you place a `+!k::` above the `!k::`.

```
*!k:: 
if GetKeyState("Shift","P")
{
        ;ToolTip, Shift
        Send {+Down Down}
        return
}
else
{
    ;ToolTip, Normal
    Send {Down Down}
}
return
```

Comment: Thatks! It works great! The final version: `code` *!k:: 
if GetKeyState("Shift","P")
{
        SendInput +{Down}
}
else
{
    SendInput {Down}
}
return `code`